# Fitnesse not able to find fixture code

Tags: fitness

I am trying to run a simple test to check if i get the correct answer to the question "whether the number is even or odd"

the FitNesse test case is like this-

!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\Users\sseth103\Desktop\FT

!|Fixture|

|number|result?|

|2     |EVEN   |

|1     |ODD    |

|3     |EVEN   |

The class file of fixture code is inside the FT folder and it calls another class which is also located at that same folder.

It is displying the error-
Could not invoke constructor for number[1],
The instance decisionTable_1.set2. does not exist etc.

Can anyone please help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake. The fixture class needs to be a part of the decision table.
I separated it and hence the error :P